Ubuntu server: Systemd-networkd-wait-online.sercice failed during startup and Invalid login bug
Ubuntu server 24.04 was working correctly for a few hours after install. After I rebooted it, there were two errors:

Systemd-networkd-wait-online.service failed every time on boot. I was also not able to use ssh when this happened but checking the status of ssh shows that it is working fine. Tried everything from the internet like increasing the timeout but nothing seems to work so I disabled this service.

Now I cannot enter into my user account. I type in username and password but it says invalid login. After trying multiple times it let me login but then I cannot use sudo because it requires password and everytime I enter my password, it says sorry try again. I am typing correct password and my keyboard is working fine.


I searched the internet and found that both of these are bugs. I am unable to resolve them. There are even some posts from 4 years ago mentioning these two bugs but I guess developers of Ubuntu cant resolve them. I installed ubuntu server in the morning and by the end of the day it is totally unuseable (not letting me log in and the server is not accessible over local network).

Please edit this post and add exactly what you have tried the steps you used and any errors you got. Tried everything from the internet does not help to understand what you have done.
